# Mkdir creates dir with 777 permission when umask is 0022

Tags: linux, docker, file-permissions, ubuntu-18.04

I am creating directories inside a container, the user is root and the output of `umask` is `0022`. But if I call `mkdir` to create new directory its default permission is `777`, other than `755`. Meanwhile, if I pull code from github, I found all directories have `777` permission.

When creating directory, I have to specify permission like: `mkdir -m 755 my_folder`, if I want the default permission is `755`.

Why is this happening? How can I make the default permissions of new directory to be `755`?

Another interesting observation:
1) This is only happening in partition mounted from ZFS server
2) For local partitions, `mkdir` acts as expected and creates all directories with `755`.

The output of `mount | grep nfs`:

```
storage-server:/mypool/work/nautilusshell on /work type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=8192,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.200.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=10.200.0.4)
storage-server:/mypool/storage on /data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=8192,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.200.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=10.200.0.4)
storage-server:/mypool/work/nautilusshell on /job type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=8192,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.200.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=10.200.0.4)
storage-server:/mypool/work/nautilusshell/master on /pod type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=8192,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.200.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=10.200.0.4)
storage-server:/mypool/work/nautilusshell on /home/nautilusshell type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=8192,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.200.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=10.200.0.4)
storage-server:/mypool/work/nautilusshell/.ssh/id_rsa on /home/nautilusshell/.ssh/id_rsa type nfs4 (ro,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=8192,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.200.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=10.200.0.4)
storage-server:/mypool/work/nautilusshell/.ssh/id_rsa.pub on /home/nautilusshell/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type nfs4 (ro,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=8192,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.200.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=10.200.0.4)
storage-server:/mypool/work/nautilusshell/.ssh/authorized_keys on /home/nautilusshell/.ssh/authorized_keys type nfs4 (ro,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=8192,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.200.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=10.200.0.4)
```

Comment: Please append the output of ```mount | grep nfs``` to your question.

Comment: I'd say it's normal since you created those directories and folders as root. Have you tried as sudo under your regular account? And when you try to edit those folders as sudo, can you write into them, delete them, etc...?